# Single quote, double quote, plus sign in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not good in JS. I tried to modify a jQuery plugin from these codes:

```
aTag +=  " style='"+innerStyle+"'";
aTag += arrow + '<span>text here</span>';
```

to these codes:

```
//aTag +=  " style='"+innerStyle+"'";
aTag += arrow + '<span style="'+innerStyle+'">text here</span>';
```

Basically I want to move the content of innerStyle from anchor tag to span tag. However, in Firebug I saw this mess after the move:

```
<span blue;"="" solid="" 1px="" border:="" 25px;="" text-indent:="" transparent;="" -80px="" 5px="" scroll="" no-repeat="" image.png")="" images="" web="" 127.0.0.1="" http:="" style="background: url(">text</span>
```

Why it works in anchor tag but not in span tag? What's the use of plus (+) signs?

Comment: What does your var innerStyle contain?

Answer (score 2):

`+` does just what it looks like it does in this case (concatenate text).  The issue here is that the HTML that is being generated in the first instance looks like this:

```
style='some contents with a " symbol'
```

while in the second case what is being generated is this:

```
style="some contents with a " symbol"
```

... which, as you can see, is broken - change your code to:

```
aTag += arrow + "<span style='" + innerStyle + "'>text here</span>";
```

and it will work.

Comment: You're right, it works! Although I'm still confused when to use single quote when to use double quote. Thanks, anyway.